# How do 'forget gates' know not to remove essential information from the Cell State in an LSTM?

Tags: neural-networks, recurrent-neural-network, lstm

This isn't completely clear to me. Say you have a massive passage that you want your LSTM to learn off of, how is it making sure it doesnt remove details from the first paragraph?

Answer (score 0):

I believe [this paper](http://www.overcomplete.net/papers/nn2012.pdf) will be of help. It explains the backpropagation algorithm.

Also note that for LSTM's that process passages, multiple LSTM blocks are used in a sequential *and* parallel manner. And additionally, neural networks are [black boxes](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/93705/meaning-of-a-neural-network-as-a-black-box): we don't know how the work internally, and they make up which details are important themselves.